# Detach list from within a list

Tags: google-docs

In Google Docs I have a main list:

```
1. asd
  1.1. zxc
  1.2. qwe
2. mnb
```

Inside list item `1.1.` I need to insert a different list completely independent from the main list, such as:

```
    1. asd
      1.1. zxc
     1. poi
     2. lkj
      1.2. qwe
    2. mnb
```

But no matter what I do, the inner list either continues the numbering form the main list or completely alter the main list numbering:

```
    1. asd
      1.1. zxc
    2. poi
    3. lkj
      3.1. qwe
    4. mnb
```

or

```
    1. asd
      1.1. zxc
    1. poi
    2. lkj
      2.1. qwe
    3. mnb
```

I tried restarting the numbering on the inner list, continuing the numbering on the main list, and changing the indentation as well, all to no avail.

Any idea how I can detach this inner list from the main one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was a little not so pretty workaround, but it works.
In my case, after list item **1.1.** I hit `Enter` to start a new list item at that same level, then hit `Enter` again, a couple mo more times, to shift the item to the previous list level until it is not part of the list anymore.

**`Enter`**

```
1. asd
  1.1. zxc
  1.2. 
  1.3. qwe
```

**`Enter` again**

```
1. asd
  1.1. zxc
2. 
  2.1. qwe
```

**`Enter` again**

```
1. asd
  1.1. zxc

  1.2. qwe
```

Then, in the empty line between **1.1.** and **1.2.** list items I have created a new bulletted list this time. When I tried to create a numbered list in there it continued the previous list instead of creating a new one.

```
 1. asd
   1.1. zxc
  * poi
  * lkj
   1.2. qwe
```

Then I converted the bulletted list into a numbered list and it ended up as I wanted it.

```
 1. asd
   1.1. zxc
  1. poi
  2. lkj
   1.2. qwe
```